# How to access a variable that gets defined inside a module?

Tags: python, module

so am writing some modules to use inside a program
but am having difficulties using the variable that i define inside the module ex:

a.py

```
def func():
   #do something to set the variable var
   var = randomValue
```

b.py

```
from a import func
func()
#how do i get var
```

I set var to global but still var is not defined.

all these answers seem great but none of theme work for my script. so here is the module, maybe you can tell me how to get `time_converted` into another script:

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
import time
import datetime

list_time = []
global time_converted
def reply_handler(msg):
    if msg.typeName == "currentTime":
        time = msg.time
        list_time.append(time)
        time_converted = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("%s"% time
                                                              )).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        return time_converted



def GetTime():
    conn = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=100)
    conn.registerAll(reply_handler)
    conn.connect()
    conn.reqCurrentTime()
    while True:
        if len(list_time) == 0:
            pass
        elif len(list_time) == 1:
            break
            conn.disconnect()
```

Comment: Unless you defined `var` outside of `func()` or return it, you can't

Comment: "all these answers seem great but none of theme work for my script" What exactly goes wrong? Do you get an error message? Do you get a wrong value? Please be specific.

Comment: I simply get "none" instead of any value

Comment: What is it that is returning `None`?

Comment: Import the previous script and print(time_converted)

Comment: Possible causes: (1) Your function `reply_handler` is setting the value of `time_converted` to `None`. (2) The `if`-block in your function `reply_handler` doesn't get executed and therefore the `return` statement isn't run. Python functions in which no `return` statement is run return the default value `None`.

Comment: `global` makes `time_converted` available everywhere in the code block being translated by the Python parser. I don't think this is what you want. I believe you want to make the results of `reply_handler` available in another module. Correct?

Comment: Yes, in the main script actually

Comment: Am able to set it as global in the module how do I extract it from there ?

Comment: I got it Bill Bell had it correct, but I had to set global inside reply_handler and return inside GetTime. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a.py**

```
from random import random

def func():
    var = random()
    return var

x = func()
```

**b.py**

```
from a import func,x

print (func(), x)
```

Output from executing b.py:

```
0.2927063452485641 0.8207727588707955
```

**Edit, in response to modified question**

When `reply_handler` itself receives a callback to process a time it uses another callback to report its result to the *main* code.

Use a callback function..

**1.py**

```
from main import receiver

def GetTime():
    reply_handler('this is the time')

def reply_handler(msg):
    receiver(msg)

GetTime()
```

**main.py**

```
def receiver(message):
    print (message)
```

Output:

```
this is the time
```

Comment: i tought it would work for me, but when i tryed it with the script i just put up it gave me "none, none"

Comment: You could consider this an alternative.

Comment: Yes, but the first way is more practical, you had it correct all along it was just that o didn't adapt it correctly to my script

Comment: I have never been accused of being too practical. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're defining the variable inside a function. To make the value of the variable available outside the function, you need to use a `return` statement. As an example:

a.py

```
def func():
    # do something to set the variable `var`
    var = 10

    return var
```

b.py

```
from a import func

# to get var
var = func()
print('The value of var is:', var)
```

See [here](https://python.swaroopch.com/functions.html) for more explanation about functions and `return` statements.

Comment: Ok let's say inside a.py var = "10" how do I print 10 inside b.py. When I print var it just gives me None.

Comment: @TarikBlaoui Try running the just updated code example.

Comment: Ok I'm am gonna adapt it to my script and see

Answer (score 0):

So this is how i was supposed to do it:

GetPrice.py

```
 from ib.opt import Connection, message
 import datetime

    list_time = []
    def reply_handler(msg):
        if msg.typeName == "currentTime":
            time = msg.time
            list_time.append(time)
            global time_converted
            time_converted = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("%s"% time
                                                                  )).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


    def GetTime():
        conn = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=100)
        conn.registerAll(reply_handler)
        conn.connect()
        conn.reqCurrentTime()
        while True:
            if len(list_time) == 0:
                pass
            elif len(list_time) == 1:
                break
                conn.disconnect()

        return time_converted
```

Main.py

```
from GetRealtime import GetTime

x =  str(GetTime())
print (x)
```

Thanks for the help guys